# Pick email, name, and phone number from contact picker intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, contactpicker

how can I get the email address correctly? Here's what I've done so far.

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public void chooseContact(){
   Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
   startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if (requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT){
      Uri contactUri = data.getData();

      // Perform the query.
      // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column.
      int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
      String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(column);

      if(phoneNumber != null)
         phoneNumber = phoneNumber.trim();

      if(phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.equals("")) {
         // This should never happen, but just in case we'll handle it
         Log.e(TAG, "Phone number was null!");
         Util.debugAsserts(false);
         return;
      }

      // Retrieve the contact name.
      column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.DISPLAY_NAME);
      String name = cursor.getString(column);

      // Retrieve the contact email address.
      column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
      String email = cursor.getString(column);

      cursor.close();

      JSONObject contacts = new JSONObject();
      String jsonString;

      try {
         contacts.put("name" , name);
         contacts.put("email" , email);
         contacts.put("phoneNumber" , phoneNumber);

         jsonString = contacts.toString();
         String encodedData = Base64.encodeToString(jsonString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

         String command = String.format("get_contact_details('%s');", encodedData);
         eaWebView.submitJavascript(command);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         throw new Error(e);
     }
  }
}
```

The above code get the name and phone number correctly but the email returns as phone number not the email address from the contact.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a `Phone-picker` in your code, by setting `setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE)` you're telling the contacts app you're only interested in a phone number.

You need to switch to a `Contact-picker`, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Then you read the result like this:

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();

// get contact-ID and name
String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long id = cursor.getLong(0);
String name = cursor.getString(1);
Log.i("Picker", "got a contact: " + id + " - " + name);
cursor.close();

// get email and phone using the contact-ID
String[] projection2 = new String[] { Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1 };
String selection2 = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cursor2 = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection2, selection2, null, null);
while (cursor2 != null && cursor2.moveToNext()) {
    String mimetype = cursor2.getString(0);
    String data = cursor2.getString(1);
    if (mimetype.equals(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
        Log.i("Picker", "got a phone: " + data);
    } else {
        Log.i("Picker", "got an email: " + data);
    }
}
cursor2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use Below Method To Fetch Contact Number, Email and Contact Name**

```
 public static  void getContactDetails(Context context){
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
            while (cur1.moveToNext()) {

                String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("Contact Details","\n Name is :"+name+" Email is: "+ email+ " Number is: "+number);

                if(email!=null){
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }
            cur1.close();
        }
    }
```

**See Below Image For Output**
[image: See The Below Output]

Comment: this code is wrong (a) doesn't answer the request of using a contact-picker, allowing the user to pick a specific contact and (b) it doesn't really query phone numbers, instead it says `number is: <an email>`